# TCL: lines start with a string character, print the line as is without any changes

Tags: tcl

A TCL script that reads a file on the filesystem named input.txt;

```
set fp [open "input.txt" r]
while { [gets $fp data] >= 0 } {
   puts $data
}
```

how do I check if the lines in the file start with a string character and print them?

Comment: Please define "string character". I'm asking because everything can be a string.

Comment: For instance if the input is as: "abc" as the first line in the file the result would be "abc"

Comment: Can you put different inputs and expected outputs for these different inputs, in your question? It would be helpful to also show what should not be in the file result, things that someone should be careful about, if applicable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
while {[gets $fp data] >= 0} {
    if {[string match -nocase {[a-z]*} $data]} {
        puts $data
    }
}
```

See [string match](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M38) man page. You might also be interested in [regexp](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm)

Comment: That check could also be done with `string is alpha -strict [string index $data 0]`; some people seem to prefer that.